# Ubuntu 14.04 running nProbe gets lro / gro errors

Tags: 14.04

I am running `NPROBE` on Ubuntu 14.04LTS (trusty), and while running it, I got this error message :

> 27/Apr/2016 16:30:39 [pro/pf_ring.c:255] WARNING: Invalid packet
>   length: [len=16512][caplen=128] 27/Apr/2016 16:30:39
>   [pro/pf_ring.c:256] WARNING: Please disable LRO/GRO on your NIC
>   (ethtool -k )

How can I fix this, and does it matter?  My Netflow flows seem to be OK from what I can tell, so what is going on? What is this?

Answer (score 0):

Offloading is a network throughput tweak.  It takes multiple packets and strings them together as a single packet, since it's faster to send one large packet, verse a bunch of smaller ones.

I can't imagine you would see a difference any which way depending on your usage, I would disable it and see if you experience any noticeable loss.

```
sudo ethtool --offload [interface eth0?] gro off
sudo ethtool --offload [interface eth0?] lro off
```